# No Files Appearing?

Tags: lumia, file-transfer

I followed the Registry Guide and now it appears in File Explorer, it shows the ammount of space used on the phone (Nokia Lumia 800) which is correct, but absolutley no files appear but i know there are, beacause i have photos in the camera roll.